# Control degree of mesh tessellation via scroll input

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

As showed in this page(result demostrated here https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_modifier_tessellation.html and source code here https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/webgl_modifier_tessellation.html), the meshes constituting the text are continuously gathering and then seperating in a loop.

What I want to do is to control the exact same effect, but through the scroll wheel. That is, the meshes should gather and form readable text when I scroll the wheel to one direction. And they should separate when I scroll the wheel to the opposite direction.

Sorry I'm extremely new to javascript and three.js, not sure if this question is too basic. Can anyone give me some suggestion about what function should be removed and what should be added for this purpose, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail to meet  your expectations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total displacement of each face of the mesh is determined by the product of a random *displacement* per face and an amplitude as seen in the vertex shader:

[*vertex shader*](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/5eba621cd7de19289fd26d64995db77f94ad49f5/examples/webgl_modifier_tessellation.html#L14C3-L34C12)

```c
void main() {
 ...
 vec3 newPosition = position + normal * amplitude * displacement;
 ...
}
```

The `amplitude` is determined by a sine function as seen in the `render` function:

[*render*](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/5eba621cd7de19289fd26d64995db77f94ad49f5/examples/webgl_modifier_tessellation.html#L224C4-L234C5)

```js
function render() {
  ...
  uniforms.amplitude.value = 1.0 + Math.sin( time * 0.5 );
  ...
}
```

To adjust the displacement of the faces by scroll input, we'll need to replace the sine function with input from the scroll wheel. It'd be something similar to this:

```
let scrollAmplitude = 0;
let factor = 1;
function init() {
  ...
  window.addEventListener( 'wheel', onWindowScroll );
}

function onWindowScroll() {
  const lastScrollPos = window.scrollY;
  scrollAmplitude = (window.height - window.scrollY) * factor;
}

function render() {
  ...
  uniforms.amplitude.value = 1.0 + scrollAmplitude;
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I was able to make it with your suggestion!